# The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<>.Find' was of type 'string', which does not match the property type of 'long?'

Tags: api, linq, asp.net-core

I am having Routing issues, and I think I know the answer, but I cannot get this to work.

```
namespace POTSwebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ShippingschedulesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly POTScontext _context;

        public ShippingschedulesController(POTScontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Shippingschedules
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>>> GetShippingschedules()
        {
            return await _context.Shippingschedules.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Shippingschedules/ID
        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Shippingschedule>> GetShippingschedule(long? id)
        {
            ActionResult<Shippingschedule> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.FindAsync(id);

            if (Shippingschedule == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Shippingschedule;
        }

        // GET: api/Shippingschedules/name
        [HttpGet("{name}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Shippingschedule>> GetShippingscheduleByName(string name)
        {
            ActionResult<Shippingschedule> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.FindAsync(name);  //<-- I think the problem is here, as it's expecting an "long" not a "string"?

            if (Shippingschedule == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Shippingschedule;
        }
```

I think the problem is in the  `api/Shippingschedules/name` method, which gives me this error:

> The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<>.Find' was of type
> 'string', which does not match the property type of 'long?'

The `FindAsync(name)` is expecting a `long` and not a `string`?

I am thinking I need to replace FindAsync() with something else, like a where<> or SQL? I am new to LINQ and API in general.

Could it also be that I've not defined the Mappings? In my Program.cs, I have this only as is shown

```
app.MapControllers();
```

Thanks

Comment: Find works with PrimaryKeys. For name, use _context.Shippingschedules.FirstOrDefault(ss => ss.Name == name);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this error occurs because the primary key of entity **Shippingschedules** has data type **lon**g, but you passed **string**.

The method FindAsync()  takes as an input the primary key of the object.
You can use:

```
await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(x => x.name.Contains(name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Legend! I had to use FirstOrDefaultAsync() because of the await, but it worked now. Cheers

Comment: Sorry question if ok... the FirstOrDefault returns only one record. How can I do this to return all (if any) records? Thanks

Comment: Hi. @Fandango68 , You can use:

`await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(x => x.name.Contains(name)).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I get - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<POTSwebAPI.Models.Shippingschedule>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<POTSwebAPI.Models.Shippingschedule>'

Comment: oh.
Return type of your function is a object, so you want to return a list object, you must change return type of your function to type `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<POTSwebAPI.Models.Shippingschedule>>>`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a route naming issue I think. Unless you are doing it somewhere else, the route to get your ShippingSchedules by name is "api/Shippingschedules/GetShippingscheduleByName"

The endpoint "api/Shippingschedules/name" more closely matches your endpoint that is accepting a long.

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Shippingschedule>> GetShippingschedule(long? id)
        {
            ActionResult<Shippingschedule> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.FindAsync(id);

            if (Shippingschedule == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Shippingschedule;
        }
```

Also the attribute seems to expect an int there, while the parameter is a long. I think that can get cleared up too.

Hopefully this fixes it!

Comment: hoang resolved it for me, but thank you anyway. So is there a primer on how to add other API multiple httpgets that explains all this easily? I've read a lot on it, but unless you know LINQ back to front, it's bloody confusing.